# How to disable highlight on ListView in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm working with Xamarin.Forms and XAML, and I'm trying to create an application that stores a list of products. I put my list of products in a ListView. This works fine. Here is my XAML:

```xml
<ListView x:Name="listSushi"
        ItemsSource="{x:Static local:myListSushi.All}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
        RowHeight="{StaticResource rowHeight}"
        >
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell>
      <ViewCell.View>
        <StackLayout Padding="5, 5, 0, 5"
                     Orientation="Horizontal"
                     Spacing="15">
          <StackLayout>
            <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" />
          </StackLayout>

          <StackLayout Padding="0, 0, 0, 0"
                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">                
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                   Font="Bold, Medium" />
                <Label Text="{Binding Description}" 
                    Font="Small"/>
          </StackLayout>

          <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                        Padding="0, 0, 10, 0">
            <Button Text=" - " 
                    HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    Command="{Binding DeleteSushiCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding Name}"
                    />
            <Label VerticalOptions="Center" 
                   Text="{Binding Number,StringFormat='{0}'}"
                   TextColor="Black"/>
            <Button Text=" + " 
                    HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                    Command="{Binding AddSushiCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding Name}"
                    />
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
      </ViewCell.View>
    </ViewCell>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

I've just the problem that if I click on a cell of my listView, the cell is highlight, and stay highlight. I've try to disable it with this code in the xaml.cs

```cs
listSushi.ItemSelected+= (object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e) => {
    // don't do anything if we just de-selected the row
    if (e.SelectedItem == null) return; 
    // do something with e.SelectedItem
    ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null; // de-select the row
};
```

But when I touch a cell, now my list is scrolling automatically. It's very strange.

Does anyone know if this is a bug, or know a fix, like if there is a property where I can disable the highlight?

Comment: If only you had accepted my answer. ;-)

Comment: API support for disabling ListView selection was added in v3.1, see Jesse's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53753049/517244) below for details.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You might try using the ItemTapped event instead, i.e.

```cs
listSushi.ItemTapped += (object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e) => {
    // don't do anything if we just de-selected the row.
    if (e.Item == null) return;

    // Optionally pause a bit to allow the preselect hint.
    Task.Delay(500);

    // Deselect the item.
    if (sender is ListView lv) lv.SelectedItem = null;

    // Do something with the selection.
    ...
};
```

I have tested this on a ListView (on an Android device) that has enough items to bring scrolling into the mix. I see no auto-scroll behavior, and your idea to set SelectedItem null to defeat the highlight works great.

Comment: While the `ViewCell` isn't selected with this solution, this will still show a "preselect" state on the `ViewCell` while the finger is shortly tapping or holding the tap on the `ViewCell`, [as viewed in this screenshot](https://imgur.com/CGoB0w9)

Comment: In all of the use cases I have run across, the preselect was the desired behavior. So much so that I updated my answer to include a delay that ensures the user gets a bit of feedback that they tapped the one they intended.

Comment: `Task.Delay(500)` doesn't delay by itself. You have to await the task it creates: `await Task.Delay(500);`.

Answer (score 23):

Current we can set ListView.SelectionMode to None to do this.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity

Comment: But, this method prevents clicks.

Answer (score 18):

I just found another method to disable the highlight effect. And i would like to share this with other users.

You can do it directly at xaml. **But this method not only disable the highlight effect, it will also disable the click event.**

You can set the IsEnabled attribute of ViewCell to false.

```
<ViewCell IsEnabled="false">
    //Your Item Layout Coding
</ViewCell>
```

In addition, you can also disable/enable each item highlight effect by binding:

```
<ViewCell IsEnabled="{Binding IsHighlightEnabled}">
    //Your Item Layout Coding
</ViewCell>
```

Hope that helps, thanks.

Comment: This will disable highlighting but it's worth noting it will also disable any button click events that might be in your ViewCell

Comment: Disables scroll too.

Comment: I have a property like IsHighlightEnabled bound to a variable that changes when my keyboard is shown or hidden. This means when I tap on a list item when the keyboard is showing, the keyboard disappears and my item is tappable. How can I block taps first, close the keyboard and then hide the keyboard?

Comment: @IanWarburton It doesn't disable scroll. Settings `IsEnabled=false` on the ListView itself would, but not if used on individual cell.

Comment: Thank you. This had taken me ages of faffing to try and prevent the highlighting but this works perfectly.

Answer (score 7):

```
YourList.ItemSelected+=DeselectItem;

 public void DeselectItem(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
  }
```

This should be helpful for your scenario. @dpfauwadel

Comment: Thank you, this was what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 6):

I am assuming you are using MVVM. In these cases I assign a null to the property after using it. In your viewmodel you seem to have a SelectedItem property since you are binding it to the SelectedItem property of the ListView. So I would do something like this:

```cs
private Product _selectedItem;
public Product SelectedItem
{
  get
  {
    return _selectedItem;
  }
  set
  {
    _selectedItem = value;

    //USE THE VALUE

    _selectedItem = null;
    NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. I had already been setting _selectedItem = null but that wasn't sufficient; adding the NotifyPropertyChanged was the key (or in my case, RaisePropertyChanged since I'm using MVVM Light). Note that I also had to set Mode=TwoWay in the XAML View (as a property for SelectedItem) in order for this to work - even though I believe TwoWay is supposed to be the default value for Mode, I had to explicitly set it.

Comment: In my case using Prism, I made it as simple as
`public RecapListViewItem SelectedRecap
 {
      get { return null; }
      set { OnPropertyChanged("SelectedRecap"); }
 }`

Comment: The other option that works for me is to use a get accessor of ```get=> null;```. The caution is you can't use SelectedItem property as the selected item. But it's quick way to prevent the item being highlighted. I then use a command binding behaviour. So also get async for the list item selection.

Answer (score 5):

On iOS mark's solution didn't solve it for me, I had to create a CustomRenderer for the list view and use that instead.

NonSelectableListView.cs (In your Forms Project)

```cs
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace YourProject
{
    public class NonSelectableListView : ListView
    {
        public NonSelectableListView()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

NonSelectableListViewRenderer.cs (CustomRenderer in your iOS project)

```cs
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

using YourProject.iOS;
using YourProject;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NonSelectableListView), typeof(NonSelectableListViewRenderer))]
namespace YourProject.iOS
{
    public class NonSelectableListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                // Unsubscribe from event handlers and cleanup any resources
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                // Configure the native control and subscribe to event handlers
                Control.AllowsSelection = false;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `Clickable` - Android equivalent of `AllowsSelection` property