# How can I disable the click in a list view? xamarin.form

Tags: xaml, xamarin, layout, xamarin.forms

I've searched and I've not found the answer yet.
I need to disable the click that happens in each item of a list and makes it be blue, as if it is selected. The problem is that my list items aren't selectables items, my list is only for the user see some informations.

Comment: provide some more info what you have tried and screen shot.

Comment: This might be what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/26682064/1771254

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `IsEnabled = "False"` as Barney said Or otherwise asign null value to selected item after selection event.

```
<ListView ItemSelected="ListView_ItemSelected" />
```

...

```
private void ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
      var list = (ListView)sender;
      list.SelectedItem = null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `IsEnabled="False"` into your `ListView` as shown here

`<ListView IsEnabled="False">`

Comment: IsEnabled="False" disabled the scroll of my list.