# Xamarin.Forms ListView Multilining and selected item color

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, multiline, listviewitem, selecteditem

Hi i've ran every link on google but i can't seem to find a solution to my 2 problems.

I'm building n app for android and IOS in Xamarin Forms and i want a List containing Text and Image Like this example.

[image]

The problems are:
[Update]
 1. I can't make the text displaying the coordinates.
 2. I can't replace the ugly orange on item selected

Like this:[Update]

[image]

Here is my code:

### MainPage

```
private ObservableCollection<Store> stores { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        storesList.BackgroundColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;
        storesList.SeparatorColor=Color.White;
        storesList.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(StoreCell));
        stores = new ObservableCollection<Store>();

        Store store1 = new Store
        {
            Name = "Pombal",
            Location = new Coordinate(39.9143958, -8.6297282).ToString()
        };
        Store store2 = new Store
        {
            Name = "Unknown",
            Location = new Coordinate(8.9143958, -39.6297282).ToString(),
            Schedule = "09:00-12:30 / 13:30-18:00"
        };

        stores.Add(store1);
        stores.Add(store2);

        storesList.ItemsSource = stores;

    }
```

---

```
<ListView x:Name="storesList" RowHeight="70" HasUnevenRows="True">

</ListView>
```

### StoreCell

```
public StoreCell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var image = new Image();
        var nameLabel = new Label { TextColor = Color.White };
        var locationLabel = new Label { TextColor = Color.White };
        var scheduleLabel = new Label { TextColor = Color.White };
        var verticaLayout = new StackLayout();
        var horizontalLayout = new StackLayout();

        //set bindings
        nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Name"));
        locationLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Location"));
        scheduleLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Schedule"));
        image.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, new Binding("Image"));

        //Set properties for desired design
        horizontalLayout.Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal;
        horizontalLayout.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill;
        image.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End;
        nameLabel.FontSize = 24;

        //add views to the view hierarchy
        verticaLayout.Children.Add(nameLabel);
        verticaLayout.Children.Add(locationLabel);
        verticaLayout.Children.Add(scheduleLabel);
        horizontalLayout.Children.Add(verticaLayout);
        horizontalLayout.Children.Add(image);

        // add to parent view
        View = horizontalLayout;
    }
```

[Update]

### The Coordinate class toString

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return X + " , " + Y;
}
```

### The Store Class

Probably doing this wrong...

```
class Store
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Schedule { get; set; }

    public Store() : this(null, null, null)
    {

    }

    public Store(String name, string location) : this(name, location, "")
    {
    }

    public Store(String name, string location, String schedule)
    {
        Name = name;
        Location = location;
        Schedule = schedule;
    }
}
```

Any thing you need just ask, thanks you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.** For "multiline" viewcells in your listview you have to set properties on your listview:

```
<ListView x:Name="storesList"
            HasUnevenRows="True"
            RowHeight="50"> 
<!-- your row height -->
<!-- ..... -->
</ListView>
```

HasUnevenRows is not necessary, but depends on your needs. I guess the name of the property tells u what it is for :D

**2.** For orange remove (Android only):
Add/Replace this line in the Resources/values/styles.xml in Android Project:

> < item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight" >#000000< /item >.

I'm unsure if the color will  be used. In my case the orange will be replaced with a default gray. This is okay for me.

For iOS highlight color:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/162154/#Comment_162154

Comment: The solution you provided is covering only one part of the question and only a single OS - Android, however the question is about both Android and iOS.

Comment: The orange highlight appears on android only. and im covering both questions.

Comment: Could be that I misunderstood your answer. My apologies.

Comment: No problem, if i really misunderstood then we'll find it out as soon as the question-creator replies

Comment: Yes its both Android and IOS

Comment: @Tiago_nes The orange selection highlight color or the row-thing? (row thing is for both i know that)

Comment: both its a single application, you can see the coment on the other answer the `RowHeight` and `HasUnevenRows` worked.

Comment: I updated my answer, so you can change the highlight color of the iOS cell as well. You have to create a custom renderer for your ViewCells

Comment: @Csharpest Updated the question with the multiline tips

Comment: Ok, first of all, you should not ask a question and then completely change the question in an edit. Instead open a new question. Next thing: you set the datatemplate to StoreCell but in the ListView Xaml you still have a custom datatemplate defined. I hope you removed that. Why do you InitializeComponent() in the storecell even though u define the layout in the .cs-file? Make it a pure cs-file then (better for performance). And please post the code of the Store-class

Comment: Updated the question, technically the question is still the same i cant have all the info in the listviewcell. I apologise something i'm new to Xamarin

Comment: @Csharpest I also changed my StoreCell class to [this](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/CustomRenderers/ViewCell/CustomRenderer/NativeCell.cs) alongside with the other CustomRenderer code.
Is it right or wrong?

Comment: Glad to hear this, but I suggest you not to put your business logic into the view. What i mean by this: dont put the observable collection on the mainpage, and dont put the bindable properties that are supposed to be your business models directly on the viewcell. Instead you should go for MVVM (xamarin works based on mvvm in the first place). [Xamarin MVVM Documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/) also has a nice example for a similiar situation where a list of data is shown through a listview. Check it out!

Comment: It takes some time to inner the mvvm approach but its definitely worth it!

Answer (score 1):

Try to:
1. Set a `RowHeight` on your `ListView` to a proper size.
2. Instead of using a nested `StackPanel` it could be easier to use a `GridView` as a template for your list items.
3. Your `Store` class should have a proper `ToString()` method on your properties. Currently you have a property of type `Coordinate` what does `ToString()` returns?

Regarding the second problem with highlighting color of the `ListItem`. There are plenty of examples all over the web and especially on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657932/how-to-disable-highlight-on-listview-in-xamarin-forms). It depends on what exactly you would like to achieve. If you want to totally disable highlighting on Android and iOS then you will have to take care of it separately for each platform using a custom renderer. Otherwise, if you would like to change or remove the orange color only on Android platform then you should check @Csharpest's solution.

Comment: its on the default i'll try to change it´

Comment: i was trying to avoid that custom renderer approach

Comment: Unfortunately all other solutions worked only on Android or iOS but not on both. In this specific case a custom renderer approach does not require that much of a custom code, so it should not be a problem.

Comment: `RowHeight` and `HasUnevenRows` helped and i can now see the schedule without having to override the toString method but the coordinates although they have  an override in to string method are not displaying at all, its just an empty space.

Comment: If Coordinate is your class simply override the ToString() method, otherwise you can create a converter: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/#Binding_Value_Converters

Comment: Updated the question with the multiline tips